# ImageData data assignment in Strict Mode

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Let's say I have such PoC code snippet for working with `canvas` raw pixel data

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  var img = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1);
  var imgData = img.data;
  img.data = imgData;
})();
```

The problem is that I get a reasonable error (I've checked in the latest Chrome and FF)

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'data' of #<ImageData>
```

So, I can disable Strict Mode and everything will become perfect, but is there any possibility to implement this in Strict Mode? Maybe i just didn't find a documentation on setter for `data`?

Thanks!

Comment: Disabling strict mode will just make it fail silently. It still won't work even if there is no error, it's just harder to debug when things fail silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read comments in code:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
  // canvas object must have size
  var w=canvas.width=100;
  var h=canvas.height=50;
  var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
  var imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,w,h);
  // In next line you retrieve array of RGBA values where each array element
  // is value between 0 and 255. Array size is size imgData.width*imgData.height
  var pixelData = imgData.data;
  pixelData[0] = 128; // Store 128 for Red channel of first pixel: (0,0)
  pixelData[5] = 128; // Store 128 for Green channel of second pixel
  imgData.data = pixelData; // Error
})();
```

You can also use `putImageData` method to modify content of CANVAS using another CanvasImageData object:

```
  var newImgData=ctx.createImageData(w,h);
  ctx.putImageData(newImgData,0,0);
```

Read about CanvasImageData in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/ImageData and in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

HTML5 canvas in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771733%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I'm using heatmap js, in heatmap js running on simple http server pure javascript code works. In my React app same code is not working.

Problem was (is), inside the library. Author had this code:

```
  img.data = imgData;
  this.ctx.putImageData(img, x, y);
```

I removed `img.data = imgData` the author is doing both, because in vanila javascript the first one doesn't throw an error. But after compilation after some Strict configuration,... the first line threw an error, so just I just removed it....

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `putImageData()` instead. Look at [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas) for help

Answer (score 0):

`ImageData.data` cannot be overwritten, but having done pixel manipulation You can change the data one pixel at a time and then use `putImageData()` to see results:

```
const id = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
for (let i = 0; i < id.data.length; i++) {
    id.data[i] = pxArray[i];
}
canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(id,0,0);
```